# How to load web content on turbolinks-android

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks-5, turbolinks-android

I have a web app which made with Ruby on Rails and enabled Turbolinks 5 but currently, I need to make a native Android app which actually designed by [Basecamp](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-android).

On their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-android) have step by step setup I'm following this steps because here (google) is not enough help for `turbolinks-android` based on their tutorial I'm setup but not loading any content like

```
#=> If I use Basecamp URL
private static final String BASE_URL = "https://basecamp.com";
```

Not changing anything always showing blank screen

```
#=> My local project
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:3000";
```

Also same not changing anything showing blank screen

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <com.basecamp.turbolinks.TurbolinksView
    android:id="@+id/turbolinks_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import com.basecamp.turbolinks.TurbolinksSession;
import com.basecamp.turbolinks.TurbolinksAdapter;
import com.basecamp.turbolinks.TurbolinksView;
```

All are same as their documentation

Appreciate if any help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still looking for an answer. I had exact the same problem with `turbolinks-android` and `Rails 5.2` web application.

Problem was caused by `content_security_policy` which is enabled by default in newest Rails versions. I fixed it by commenting out content in `config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb` file.

Also a good tip for future problems - use `adb logcat` command with devise connected via USB. It will show you what exactly causing an error.

Answer (score 0):

Their example project is not working anymore. Probably because of its [deprecated](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-android/wiki/Turbolinks-Android-Adapter-1.x-Deprecation). But they use it in their application so it's not dead yet. Example project's first problem is it needs 2 additional libraries to use:

```
implementation 'com.basecamp:turbolinks:1.0.9' // Turbolinks
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2' // Important addition 1
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1' // Important addition 2
```

Also, HTTP without SSL isn't working so you need to use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to tunnel your connection with HTTPS.

You can look at my working example at [Github](https://github.com/yunusemredilber/groupath-android)